# Scaffolded password-reset page breaks user passwords

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

I am having issues with logging in after resetting a password, with scaffolded Identitity pages (forgot password, reset password, login).

I scaffolded the ForgotPassword and PasswordReset pages because I wanted admins to be able to reset users' passwords for them. Additionally, I am using a custom IdentityUser class that inherits IdentityUser. Everything else works (including logins, logouts, etc.).

The password reset **doesn't** work. In tracing the flow - the password reset token is generated correctly. The user receives it, goes to the correct page, it gets decoded correctly. The issue seems to be happening when the new password gets hashed - I don't know what algorithm it's using, but the resultant hash is obviously different than the initial. I did a test where I typed down a password, copy-and-pasted it into both the reset field and the login field, and got a credential error!!!

Out of curiosity I called the following function which I assumed should've given me the same hash as on the SQL server, and compared it to the hash stored there (my local test DB of course)

```
var test = _signInManager.UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(
    await _signInManager.UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email),
    Input.Password);
```

Here are the results:

Password:

> ABCDEFG12345

Password hasher in ResetPassword:

> AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEBhYZXqCx2Y43vqlB9bQ0Cf6AjgcyckVYDQSm+D+t8Zmv8V9Mx/E6/w5LyFzGOqIFQ==

Sql DB hash for that user:

> AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEItXHv1WYksR5AU6KUYHrF4Xrlnlzi2EM+LzecmUqrcz1Zx2JiUVLkHMk7ZSgqfiXw==

Password hasher in Login:

> AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEGUvKsoSmQ5RFQWLysQqAv6BZtgMEup1bPEYZSlJ7MzzhMVQ+20qhKapzcX+ISOLOg==

What gives? Where's the issue? Has anyone experienced this or has ways to troubleshoot this further? Am I using the wrong password hashing function to compare what gets put in the server? Is it a localhost vs. deployed issue?

For what it's worth, I checked and the DB hash *does* change after each password reset, so it's not as if the code isn't doing anything. It seems like the left and right hands aren't talking to each other.

Comment: "Passwords must have at least one non alphanumeric character.
Passwords must have at least one lowercase ('a'-'z').
"  Check with your password `ABCDEFG12345`.

Comment: Interesting, so you're saying the password reset page doesn't do any sort of validation on the password? That's a big problem. Also confusing why the hashes would be different. I'll try it out and get back to you.

Comment: As an update, I think the issue is with some version mismatching. I tried the same process on my desktop, which uses Identity 6.0.8 as opposed to 6.0.10, and it works fine. So I think between my two computers there's a version mismatch somewhere.